# Save video with AVFoundation

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, avfoundation, video-recording

I'am using the AVFoundation for an "In app" camera recorder. I can actually record video in a UIView with `AVCaptureSession`, but I'm looking for a way to save these video somewhere in my iPad (Album, Documents folder,...).

I'v tried to use :

```
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput
AVCaptureDeviceInput
```

But still not working. Is there another way to save the video recorded by `AVCaptureSession`?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *docPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/yourrecoredfile"];
[dataFile writeToFile:docPath 
          atomically:YES 
            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
               error:NULL];
```

Comment: What is `dataFile` supposed to be? Because the `AVCaptureSession` does not have a `writeToFile` method. And by the way I'm not sur if I record correctly, I do it with `[session startRecord]` and stop it with `[session stopRecord]` where session is an instance of `AVCaptureSession`

Comment: But i'm not sure if my datas are correctly recorded, i'm looking for use AVCaptureMovieOutput and AVCaptureDeviceInput, but I have no idea how to use them

Comment: see this link it may be help : http://www.benjaminloulier.com/articles/ios4-and-direct-access-to-the-camera

Comment: I did the same stuff that the link above, : Instantiate  an AVCaptureMovieFileOutput then add it to the `AVCaptureSession`. After I start the session : `[session startRunning];` and `[movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[self tempFileURL] recordingDelegate:self];`. When I push a button I stop it : `[session stopRunning];` and the videoOutput  `[movieFileOutput stopRecording];` but nothing happen ! I'm probably missing something but what? Anyway thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nil if you dont want obj c method with selector  which i used for a prompt.

```
 func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {

    if (error != nil) {
        print("Error recording movie: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    } else {

        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL.path, nil, #selector(CameraController.video(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

    }
    outputURL = nil

}
```